# Are there frameworks for reactive programming on backend?

Tags: reactjs, reactive-programming, ngrx

Facebook React and Angular 2 both encourage reactive programming (or at least, are built in a way that makes it easy to take advantage of reactive programming).

Both of these are aimed at building frontend clients.

Is there anything analogous for building backends? In my mind, it seems like it makes a lot of sense to build it that way if I have a reactive frontend. It'd make it easy to have a clean history of (backend) application state, which will in turn make it really easy to keep things in sync with a frontend client that has local storage, or to keep things in sync between two clients.

If there isn't, why not? Is there some common sense reason I'm not getting for why reactive programming makes sense on the frontend, but not on the backend?

CLARIFICATION UPDATE: I'm aware of reactivex.io, but I am more wondering whether there is an opinionated framework like Angular 2 or React which encourages building your backend with "reducers" and "selectors", and for which every change in the backend corresponds to some "action" that can be recorded to make debugging clean.

Comment: Apparently there are (http://reactivex.io/), but I rarely use it on my back-end solution (ASP.NET MVC). Why? Because the different paradigm in developing front-end and back-end apps. Front-end SPA tends to be loaded once to the browser window and sit there firing/waiting for asynchronous events; where-as my back-end threads will only fire up if there's any incoming request and dispose right after the request is served.

Comment: ahhh, I see. So are you saying that for the purpose of speed, it isn't as important? How about for the purpose of code cleanliness / separation of concerns / making it easy to debug how your backend has changed? Also, having a record of these actions seems to be useful for synchronizing with a frontend local storage? is there a reason why this isn't as useful as I'm imagining?

Comment: aren't incoming requests basically asynchronous events? why not use reactive programming on the backend?

Answer (score 2):

There a plenty of implementations for backend code like Rx.Net and RxJava, you can see the full list here http://reactivex.io/languages.html.

For backend code that receives network events like sensor data, it makes sense to use reactive code.

Comment: Thanks @Toan, I'm aware of reactivex.io, but I was more wondering if there's some opinionated framework (or even some packages / gems) that are built for the reactive paradigm. Something where your backend only changes through "actions" that are emitted, and you implement "reducers" that take actions to update the state. (I've updated my question to clarify this).

Comment: I have not seen any opinated framework but I have used the library for .Net. It is pretty cool. Cheers.